# General function to withdraw any ERC-20/ ERC-721 token sent to a contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, vyper

I am deploying a contract today.

Tomorrow if some user mistakenly sends ETH to my contract, I can retrieve or return it if I have implemented a payable and a send function.

```
@external
@payable
def __default__():
    # a basic payable to enable receiving incoming eth
    log ethReceived(msg.value, msg.sender)


@external
def withdraw(_to: address):
    # for sending out any eth transferred in by mistake
    assert msg.sender == self.owner
    log ethSent(self.balance, msg.sender)
    send(_to, self.balance)
```

But what if some user mistakenly sends any other ERC-20 token or ERC-721 NFT to my contract; is there a general function I could have implemented in my contract, so I can retrieve those, as long as they follow their respective standards? I won't know the token contract in advance, it could be any valid ERC-20 or ERC-721.

Vyper code preferred, but Solidity answers or examples are also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close with your ETH example, just need to adapt to the ERC20 standard.

```
# @version 0.3.2

from vyper.interfaces import ERC20

@external
def withdraw(token: ERC20, receiver: address):
    assert msg.sender == self.owner

    balance: uint256 = token.balanceOf(self)
    log TokenSent(token, msg.sender, balance)
    token.transfer(receiver, balance)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any equivalent for ERC721 tokens?

Comment: you would do something similar, except using the signature from the ERC721 interface - `token.transferFrom(self, receiver, balance)`.

Answer (score 1):

My contract [ERC20Recover](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-contracts/blob/090ed8f0636ffa4a69aec5e74344a4b12ab734da/contracts/token/erc20/ERC20Recover.sol) does exactly what you're looking for.

If you're using an npm package manager, you can install my contracts package like this:

```bash
yarn add @prb/contracts
// or
npm install @prb/contracts
```

Then in your Solidity contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.8.4;

import "@prb/contracts/token/erc20/ERC20Recover.sol";

contract MyContract is ERC20Recover {
    constructor(address nonRecoverableToken) {
        // Set a list of non-recoverable tokens.
        nonRecoverableTokens.push(nonRecoverableToken);
        isRecoverInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

See how this is used in the wild here:

- [IHToken](https://github.com/hifi-finance/hifi/blob/fab6b73cbe796a46728cc152629bb3e39f7b6902/packages/protocol/contracts/core/h-token/IHToken.sol#L15-L19)
- [HToken](https://github.com/hifi-finance/hifi/blob/fab6b73cbe796a46728cc152629bb3e39f7b6902/packages/protocol/contracts/core/h-token/HToken.sol#L90-L92)

Comment: This is great, i've actually had your contract open in one tab and was seeing how this converts to vyper. Do you have any similar suggestions for ERC721?

Comment: nope sorry I don't know anything about ERC721.